# If site is build for modern browser, is box-shadow a perfect alternative to border?

Tags: css, box-shadow

Border example

`border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;`

Box-shadow example

`box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #d9d9d9;`

If site is build for modern browser, is box-shadow a perfect alternative to border?

Answer (score 1):

A border is part of the element and influences its size. A shadow does not.

Also, browser support for old browsers might be missing.